# Start applications in Systemtray

Tags: cinnamon, startup-applications, system-tray

I'm using Cinnamon as my DE.
I inserted the Seafile Sync Client (seafile-applet) to start synchonisation automatically.

But it is really annoying, that the application-window starts, too.

So is there a way to start applications in a minimized or system-tray mode?

Answer (score 0):

There's an option where you can define to start the Seafile client minimized.
You can find the Seafile settings dialog by right clicking the tray icon and choose »settings«.